# GIT Fogbugz integration

Tags: git, fogbugz, websvn

What would you use instead of WebSVN when tying Git into FogBugz?

Answer (score 1):

[gitweb](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/Gitweb) could be considered the equivalent of websvn for git.

Take a look at this project which aims to [integrate gitweb with FogBugz](http://www.softwarerealisations.com/fogbugz-git-integration.html).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this GitHub integration project:

https://github.com/johnreilly/github-fogbugz

Not a generic `git` integration, but helpful for GitHub/Fogbugz users.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.fogcreek.com/fogbugz-github-integration/ Or you could do it the way they instruct you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I made an attempt at a post-receive hook to integrate Gitweb diff links into FogBugz. The main difference between the configured Git integration and SVN/others is that the links are to full commits rather than individual file diffs. This was so we could integrate with several projects without creating a FogBugz repository configuration for each one.

https://gist.github.com/4071548

Please see the comments for usage notes, suggestions welcome.